# unable to remove canvas and change src by their id : fabric js

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

i want to remove canvas by their id i tried assigning them id can call remove method , but it not works:

see link : http://jsfiddle.net/mishragaurav31/kcyKJ/

html code:

remove itchange it

js code

```
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

        function getObjectById(id) {
            canvas.forEachObject(function(o) {
                if (o.id === id) {
                    return o;
                }
            });
            return null;
        }

    var img = "http://edudemic.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/jail_photo.jpg";

        fabric.Image.fromURL(img, function (source) {
        img = source.set({
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            angle: 0,
            id:'moveit'
        });
        canvas.add(img);
        canvas.renderAll();
        });

      document.getElementById('download').onclick = function() {
          alert('hii');
        var removeit = getObjectById('moveit');
          canvas.remove(removeit);
      };

      document.getElementById('changeimage').onclick = function() {
          alert('hii');
        getObjectById('moveit').src="http://www.meandmylaptop.com/uploads/5/8/1/2/5812329/7801574.png";
          canvas.renderAll();
      };

document.getElementById('changeimage').onclick = function() {
          alert('hii');
        getObjectById('moveit').src="http://www.meandmylaptop.com/uploads/5/8/1/2/5812329/7801574.png";
          canvas.renderAll();
      };
```

Comment: `var removeit = getObjectById('moveit');` is null. So somehow you're setting the id but id is not being applied.

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ianwong/qdwv5mh6/)

Change

```
  alert('hii');
  var removeit = getObjectById('moveit');
  canvas.remove(removeit);
```

To

```
//      alert('hii');
canvas.remove(img);
//   var removeit = getObjectById('moveit');
//      canvas.remove(removeit);
```

Comment: what if i want to change src :img.setAttribute("src",image);

Comment: yeah but you are adding new image not chnage old one src

Comment: @mour [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ianwong/qdwv5mh6/3/) use *setAttribute* to change